# На Яндекс.Картах иногда перестают отображаться маркеры

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api, яндекс-карта-api

Использую API Яндекс.Карт для отображения карты с метками на сайте. Меток на одной карте может быть от 100 до 1000 и больше.
Есть 4 страницы с картами. Все работают через один шаблон, выводя соответствующую информацию по if/else. То есть код один для всех 4-х страниц с картами.
Периодически перестают отображаться метки на какой-нибудь одной из 4-х карт. Показывается просто пуская карта.

Сейчас снова не отображаются маркеры на одной и 4 карт. Не отображаются в нескольких браузерах. Проверено в Firefox, Google Chrome, Яндекс Браузере.

Однако *с телефона* никаких проблем нет, все 4 карты корректно работают и отображают все метки. Так же проверено в нескольких браузерах.

**В чём может быть причина такого разного отображения маркеров на разных устройствах?
В чём может быть причина периодической пропажи меток с одной из карт?**

**Может проблема связана с ограничениями на запросы по API Яндекс.Карт?** Пишут, что при пересечении лимита карты отключаются. Но опять же с телефона все работают, а с компьютера не все отключились

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Необходимо разбираться не гипотетически, а на реальных примерах. Ничего, кроме разной скорости загрузки кода и данных пока в голову не лезет, может что-то где-то загружается или запрашивается раньше времени. Если сюда ссылки на страницы с нерабочими картами не хотите, вам придётся обратиться в поддержку Яндекс.